# Processing list in Makefile

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

In bash, when I want to iterate in a recursive list of pdf files, without the extension, I could do the following:

```
for file in `find mypath -type f -name '*.pdf' -printf "%f\n"`
do
    echo "${file%.*}"
done
```

This works perfectly, and I get a list of the pdf files without the extension.

But if I try to do the same in a Makefile, I get empty output:

```
my_test:
    @for file in `find mypath -type f -name '*.pdf' -printf "%f\n"`; \
    do \
        echo "${file%.*}"; \
    done; \
```

do you have an idea why this is happening?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put in an extra `$`:

```
echo "$${file%.*}"; \
```

In your command Make expands the first `$`, interprets `${` as nothing, and things unravel fast. With `$$`, the first `$` escapes the second and the `${...}` gets passed to the shell.